# how can i bring more than 10 data at once by using react-native FlatList?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i have data like this

```
    singlePost?.Comments = [
        0: {id: 82, content: "부모1", responseTo: null}
        1: {id: 83, content: "자식1", responseTo: 82}
        2: {id: 84, content: "부모2", responseTo: null}
        3: {id: 85, content: "자식2", responseTo: 84}
        4: {id: 86, content: "부모3", responseTo: null,}
        5: {id: 87, content: "자식3", responseTo: 86}
        6: {id: 88, content: "부모4", responseTo: null}
        7: {id: 90, content: "자식4", responseTo: 88,}
        8: {id: 91, content: "부모5", responseTo: null}
        9: {id: 92, content: "자식5", responseTo: 91,}
        10: {id: 93, content: "부모6", responseTo: null}
        11: {id: 94, content: "자식6", responseTo: 93}
                             ]
```

when i try to render all of my data by using FlatList, only 10 pieces of data are rendered(whice is id: 82~ 92) for the first time, and automatically re-rendered, then all the data is rendered. (whice is id: 82~ 94)

like this

```
     console.log(item)

 

  item 0: {id: 82, content: "부모1", responseTo: null}
  item 1: {id: 83, content: "자식1", responseTo: 82}
  item 2: {id: 84, content: "부모2", responseTo: null}
  item 3: {id: 85, content: "자식2", responseTo: 84}
  item 4: {id: 86, content: "부모3", responseTo: null,}
  item 5: {id: 87, content: "자식3", responseTo: 86}
  item 6: {id: 88, content: "부모4", responseTo: null}
  item 7: {id: 90, content: "자식4", responseTo: 88,}
  item 8: {id: 91, content: "부모5", responseTo: null}
  item 9: {id: 92, content: "자식5", responseTo: 91,}

  item 0: {id: 82, content: "부모1", responseTo: null}
  item 1: {id: 83, content: "자식1", responseTo: 82}
  item 2: {id: 84, content: "부모2", responseTo: null}
  item 3: {id: 85, content: "자식2", responseTo: 84}
  item 4: {id: 86, content: "부모3", responseTo: null,}
  item 5: {id: 87, content: "자식3", responseTo: 86}
  item 6: {id: 88, content: "부모4", responseTo: null}
  item 7: {id: 90, content: "자식4", responseTo: 88,}
  item 8: {id: 91, content: "부모5", responseTo: null}
  item 9: {id: 92, content: "자식5", responseTo: 91,}
  item 10: {id: 93, content: "부모6", responseTo: null}
  item 11: {id: 94, content: "자식6", responseTo: 93}
```

this is my code

```
          return (
                <ContaiFlatListner
                data={singlePost?.Comments}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
                
                ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyItem />}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                    console.log("item:",item),
                    <TodoItem
                    item={item}
                    />
                )}
                />
            );
```

so what i want is that when i try to render, i want to render all of my data (whice is id: 82~ 94) at once for the first time

i think the reason why this issue happend is that FlatList bring data very slow...

then how can i fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the following property on the FlatList:

`initialNumToRender={a number larger than 10}`

However the docs do detail the downsides of doing this which you should be aware of https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

Comment: thank you it works and i will read what you linked !!!